# ROS Answers SE migration: Tree frames tf

Tags: ros, image-geometry, transformations, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

This is my scenario:

[image description http://subir.cc/images/img201ryr.jpg](http://subir.cc/images/img201ryr.jpg)

In a node I publish the webcam image and retrieve the coordinates x,y when the user clicks on the screen. After I publish the coordinates.

```
void my_mouse_callback( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param ){

switch( event ){
    case CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE: 
        break;
    case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        break;
    case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        //publicamos x e y
        geometry_msgs::PointStamped pixel;
        pixel.header.frame_id = "webcam";
        pixel.header.stamp = ros::Time();       
        pixel.point.x = x;
        pixel.point.y = y;
        pixel.point.z = 0.0;        
        pub.publish(pixel); 
        break;
}
```

}

In the other node I subscribe to the coordinates and I calculate the ray of pixel with [projectPixelTo3dRay().](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/image_geometry/html/c++/classimage__geometry_1_1PinholeCameraModel.html#ad52a4a71c6f6d375d69865e40a117ca3)

```
void point_callback(const geometry_msgs::PointStampedConstPtr& p){
     tf::TransformListener listener;
     cv::Point2d pixel(p->point.x,p->point.y);
     ROS_INFO("Pixel (%.f,%.f)",pixel.x,pixel.y);
     cv::Point3d ray=model.projectPixelTo3dRay(pixel);
     ROS_INFO("ray.x: %.5f ray.y: %.5f ray.z: %.5f\n",ray.x,ray.y,ray.z);
```

}

As the camera is on the table, I want to calculate 3d point in the world with Z=0. I want to use [tf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf), but do not know how to create the tree to make the transformations.

What tree should I create?

World-->base_camera-->optic_centre

World-->camera

...

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44989/tree-frames-tf/) by [Alberto Martín](https://answers.ros.org/users/3121/alberto-mart%C3%ADn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2012-10-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One motivation to have distinct "optical" frames and "camera" frames comes from a matter of modularity. As you know, there are certain assumptions about the orientation of an "optical" frame (z out, x right, y down) with respect to the image data and projection, and this projection is almost always generated from a calibration routine, and needs to be with respect to some reference frame. It's good practice to perform this calibration with respect to some frame that is rigidly attached to the camera. If this reference frame is something like the "world" frame, then you can't change the pose of the camera based on a pose estimator or articulated base. In your case, it looks like the camera is basically fixed to the world, so you won't really get any benefit from doing this, but one more transform in the tree won't hurt, so you might as well calibrate it to a rigid "camera" frame.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1